# Angular directives for sorting nested lists, does not move cards AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop

I use to my project :

**Angular directives for sorting nested lists using the HTML5 Drag & Drop API**

[Link](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists)

I did that when I catch card and I move her to second list, after drop he disappear and is show error in console

> TypeError: scope.$eval(...).splice is not a function Ślad stosu:
>   @http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular-drag-and-drop-lists.js:421:13
>   $eval@http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:18161:16
>   $apply@http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:18261:20
>   @http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular-drag-and-drop-lists.js:420:11
>   defaultHandlerWrapper@http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:3734:3
>   eventHandler@http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:3722:9

Good thing that he dissappear because slice is work but I need now to make somewhow to save this card in the list to which i moved

index.ejs

```
<div ng-repeat="list in lists" >
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">
  <div id="tasks" >
    <h3>{{ list.name }} {{$index}}</h3>
   <ul dnd-list="list">
         <li ng-repeat="card in list.cards | orderBy: 'position'"
        dnd-draggable="card"
        dnd-moved="dragAndDrop($parent.$index, $index)"
        dnd-effect-allowed="move"
        dnd-selected="models.selected = card"
        ng-class="{'selected': models.selected === card}"
        >
        {{card.name}}
    </li>
      <!--<li dnd-draggable ng-repeat="card in list.cards | orderBy: 'position'">{{ card.name }} {{ card.position }}<button ng-click="take($index)">HERE</button>{{ $index }}</li>
      </ul>-->
      <form ng-submit="addTask(list._id, newTask, $index)">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newTask" placeholder="add a new task" required />
        </form>
        <button ng-click="changePosition()">change</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the most important piece of controller;

```
$scope.dragAndDrop = function (listIndex, index) {
    console.log(listIndex);
    console.log(index)
    $scope.lists[listIndex].cards.splice(index, 1);
}
    $scope.loadLists = function () {
        return ApiService.staff.list()
            .then(function (resp) {
                $scope.lists = resp;
                console.log($scope.lists)
            })
    }
```

I think that i must somehow run function in controller with name "scope.$eval(...).splice" but i do not know how, can tell me someone how to write it in controller, or some other way.